# Why are quarterly EPS values different on different sites?

Tags: financial-statements, sec

Looking up EPS values for several companies I noticed that sometimes webpages (e.g. marketwatch.com, iextrading.com) report different values than the ones found on the SEC 10-Q filings. Why does this happen? Which ones are the correct ones?

**Edit:**
With respect to marketwatch, it appears I was confused by some companies having different fiscal years (e.g. MCFT has a fiscal year that begins on July 1 and ends June 30) and including their "fourth quarter" data in their 10-K instead of filing a separate 10-Q. That said IEX trading's api does report different values for "actualEPS" on the following links:
https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/MCFT/earnings
https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/GOOGL/earnings

Comment: Can you give an example company for which this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finance sites often "normalize" financial statements to make them more comparable, while a company may report factors like EPS in a slightly different way. Some examples I've seen are the treatment of non-recurring income and expenses, differences in what is considered "income" versus an "expense", and the use of diluted versus outstanding shares.

Since EPS and other factors are not subject to accounting rules in the same way that financial statements are, it requires some knowledge to look at the raw and adjusted financial statements to reconcile any differences.

Answer (score -2):

So, Companies can misguide creditors and investors to entice them to loan or invest money based on inaccurate or manipulated numbers, such as EPS. It is up to the creditor or investor to determine if the numbers, such as EPS, that are being reported are accurate or not. Due diligence is required in order to crunch the numbers oneself and compare the results to what is being reported. The difference between the actual numbers and what is being shown, reported, can be extremely great. I have found EPS reported at -0.1 and when I crunched the numbers, the actual EPS is 0.15 and a different site has the EPS reported at 0.22. This is a huge discrepancy, be careful my friends. Fraud and deceit run rampant. Just look up fractional reserve banking which is clearly a fraud.

Comment: I sensed from the first line what kind of answer this would be, and "*fractional reserve banking ... is clearly a fraud*" confirmed it.